# Add new table on Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, azure-mobile-services

Can anyone explain me what is the exact procedure to add a new table on an Azure database?
I'm literally going crazy!!!
I download the sample project from Azure for backend mobile and forms application, but I can't add new table in any way. 
Every change I made, I have exception (internal server error).
I create a new data object MyClass:EntityData
and create a Controller in the appropriate procedure. I've also added a Dbset reference in database context.
Not Work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different versions of this question:

1. "I am using a Node.js Backend - how do I create a table?" - Answer - define the table in your node code in the tables directory - it will be created for you.
2. "I am using an ASP.NET Backend - how do I create a table?" - Answer - this is an Entity Framework problem.  Create an EF Migration to create the database and apply the migration when you upload the code.

References:

- Node:
  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#howto-dynamicschema
- ASP.NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: I use Asp.net and I've read the reference, but when I start local mobile service I can't try the get method to create my table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged Visual Studio, just use SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools), connect to your Azure database and create a new table. It's no different than creating a local SQL Server table.

You could also create a CREATE TABLE script and execute it against your Azure database. You could also use the schema synchronization feature within SSDT to compare a local copy of the table and synch it with your Azure DB.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the whole procedure for .net backend, but damn it! still Invalid sync operation: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.